# Derivative Service 400 Bad Request

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

Sometimes when accessing the Forge Derivative Service API via

`GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/manifest/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c3RlbW4vNTcwMzBkMzBjNzFkZWVmNDBkNjViNDAxLTBCOTlVamtJMXBnN2FkbE16UzJKSExVbzNjV3MtMEI5OVVqa0kxcGc3YWRHOTJlbVJtTnpablJ6TnhRV2N5V1hOT05qZEdPV2xwYVhoclBRLXVuZGVmaW5lZC5kd2c`

I get the response

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Bad Request</H1>
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;7&#46;425832b8&#46;1500624784&#46;0
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

How can I find out what it was about my request that the server did not understand. This is a simple `GET` request so I'm not sure what I am doing so that my request is not understood.

Comment: Without seeing the code it is hard to tell what could cause the issue

Comment: What about the supplied reference number? Doesn't that have give debugging information on your end?

Comment: Did you want to download derivative files from the Forge server?? If yes, you can not call API in this way. The right way is `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/{{Base64URN}}/manifest/{{URL encoded file URN}}`.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no endpoint like you are describing ([see list](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/)): `derivativeservice/v2/manifest/:urn` doesn't exist, aren't you missing something? Which endpoint are you trying to call? Maybe [manifest](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/)?

Second, when I base64 [DECODE](https://www.base64decode.org/) your URN, I'm getting:

`urn:adsk.objects:os.object:stemn/57030d30c71deef40d65b401-0B99UjkI1pg7adlMzS2JHLUo3cWs-0B99UjkI1pg7adG92emRmNzZnRzNxQWcyWXNONjdGOWlpaXhrPQ-undefined.dwg`

This ***undefined*** at the end is a bit suspicious and may be causing this problem. Can you double check the URN **before** encoding it? If that's a file on a bucket, seems incomplete/incorrect anyway.

Comment: Hi, the undefined is intentional and not cause for this issue. Thanks for highlighting thought.

Comment: This url works despite not being listed on that page. Maybe this issue is related to my other issue I logged 4 months ago? https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io/issues/12

Comment: Can you share a Token for this URN so I can test it here? My email is my first [dot] last name @autodesk.com